# Lentitud en red cuando no hay Internet

Tags: linux, centos, networking

No se si es el grupo indicado, pero aqui va la consulta:

Tengo en un cliente una red simple:
· Router (Ubiquiti), conectado al modem del ISP
· Enlace Punto a Punto con otro edificio.

Todo funciona correctamete, excepto cuando se cae Internet. 
Cuando eso sucede, la red se vuelve extremadamente lenta (toda la LAN, incluyendo los enlaces).

¿Se les ocurre qué puede estar pasando?

Comment: con lento te referís a latencia alta o a ancho de banda bajo?

Comment: Gracias por responder, me refiero a latencia sumamente alta.

Comment: Suele ser muy común, los equipos van a los dns a resolver nombres por un montón de motivos. Yo probaría a desconfigurar el dns en un equipo o a meter en el hosts todos los servidores con su ip local. El dns cuando no funciona la conexión con internet da muchos problemas.

Comment: Gracias! Voy a probar la sugerencia.